# "Program ended with exit code: 0" appears towards the beginning of my output?

Tags: c++, xcode

So my code is basically supposed to read a postfix expression and compute the value. This is my code so far and it seems to work except that the "Program ended with exit code: 0" appears towards the beginning of my output every time I run it on Xcode. Is there an error in my code that is causing this? Also, I'm supposed to only have the user input the value of a variable with the same name once but will always have to enter it twice. Is there a way around this that is simple?

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{

char input = 'y';
while (input == 'y')
{
    std::string expression;
    std::stack<int> myStack;

    std::cout << "Enter a postfix expression with a $ at the end: ";
    std::getline(std::cin,expression);


    int i = 0;


    std::istringstream ss(expression);
    while (ss >> expression)
    {
        if (expression[i] >= 'a' && expression[i] <= 'z')
        {
            int number = 0;
            std::cout << "Enter the value of " << expression << ": ";
            std::cin >> number;
            myStack.push(number);
        }
        else if (expression[i] >= '0' && expression[i] <= '9')
        {
            int number = std::stoi(expression);
            myStack.push(number);
        }
        else
        {

            switch (expression[i]) {
                case '+':
                {
                    int number1 = myStack.top();
                    myStack.pop();
                    int number2 = myStack.top();
                    myStack.pop();

                    int total = number1 + number2;
                    myStack.push(total);
                    break;
                }

                case '-':
                {
                    int number1 = myStack.top();
                    myStack.pop();
                    int number2 = myStack.top();
                    myStack.pop();

                    int total = number1 - number2;
                    myStack.push(total);
                    break;
                }

                case '*':
                {
                    int number1 = myStack.top();
                    myStack.pop();
                    int number2 = myStack.top();
                    myStack.pop();

                    int total = number1 * number2;
                    myStack.push(total);
                    break;
                }

                case '/':
                {
                    int number1 = myStack.top();
                    myStack.pop();
                    int number2 = myStack.top();
                    myStack.pop();

                    int total = number1 / number2;
                    myStack.push(total);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\tFinal value = " << myStack.top() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Continue(y/n)? ";
    std::cin >> input;

    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();


}
return 0;
}
```

[This is the output after entering 'n' to terminate the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNUnn.png)

Comment: Doesn't appear to be anything to do with this code. Something else that your GUI program runs in the terminal. This is the unfortunate downside to using overcomplicated pretty GUIs to learn C++, that hides behind pretty buttons and menus. There's too much stuff going on under the covers, and when something goes sideways it's going to be a lot of digging to figure out what's being run in the terminal together with your code. Do yourself a favor and try to learn C++ using vi or emacs, a shell, and a Makefile, so you really understand how everything works. You'll thank yourself in a few years.

Comment: I copied your program and tested with a here doc. simulating inputs `123 234 + $` `y` `234 2 * $` `n`. It computed `357` `246` and terminated regularly. [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37f6b63e7ecc0e06). So, I would agree with Sam that your IDE might be broken.

Comment: Btw. I assume your linked image contains a snapshot of your console window i.e. text only. It probably is better to copy/paste the text instead of inserting an image. (I cannot open image links as my company's firewall blocks imgur.)

Comment: The exit code is usually (certainly on OSes that I have worked with) whatever you return from `main`. Normally it isn't printed to the terminal, but because many programs use it to indicate errors, I imagine your IDE chose to actually show it (even when it is zero, which often indicates successful termination). Why on earth it shows in the middle of the output I could only guess, probably an IDE bug of sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to be resolved for me in Xcode Version 10.1 beta 3 (10O45e)